# Error "Assignment cannot be null" trying to create assignment in workfront to a team

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I am trying to assign a **team** to a task in Workfront and keep getting the error "assignment cannot be null".  I am providing a valid TeamID and setting the field isTeamAssignment set to true.  If I make the same call by trying to assign an individual, it works fine, but I am of course trying to assign a team to a task.

Here is an example of my POST request (I have replaced some of the actual values with VALUE):

Method: POST
URL: https://ent.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/assgn

Data: sessionID=VALUE&teamID=VALUE&projectID=VALUE&taskID=VALUE&isTeamAssignment=true&status=AA"

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your authentication (sessionID or API key) you should pass only two values to the assign method: objID and objCode. Ensure that you are calling the assign method within the object to which you want to assign a team.

For example: `<baseurl>/task/<taskID>/assign?objID=<teamID>&objCode=TEAMOB&<authentication>`

Ensure that you make the call as a PUT method.